# What does GA returning visitors calculation mean?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm a bit confused as to what 'returning visitors' mean in Google Analytics. If a user visited my site a year ago, and now returning, will he be considered a returning visitor? Is there any way to specify a time-frame, and calculate stuff like 'visitors that come at least twice a month'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google Analytics 'visitor' is tracked by a unique cookie. If the cookie is present since the last visit the visitor is counted as returning.

For more GA definitions see http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/google-analytics-definitions

Also GA´s [Interpreting Reports](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/interpreting_reports_visits/index.html) might be of interest.

For GA´s cookie information see [Google Analytics Cookie Usage on Websites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the expiration of that cookie is? I've seen in you link there's a cookie for 2yrs, but not sure this is the one that is being used for returning calc.

Comment: For an explanation of GA cookies see the google support document @ https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage